# How do i enable esata hot plug with marvell controllers in a gigabyte z77 mobo?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, esata

I have a new gigabyte ga-Z77x-UD3H mobo (http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4441#sp)that is supposed to have:
2 x SATA 6Gb/s connectors (SATA3 0/SATA3 1) supporting up to 2 SATA 6Gb/s devices
4 x SATA 3Gb/s connectors (SATA2 2~5) supporting up to 4 SATA 3Gb/s devices
Marvell 88SE9172 chip: 0.2 x eSATA 6Gb/s connectors on the back panel supporting up to 2 SATA 6Gb/s devices.

The problem is the Marvell ports do not seem to be hot plug capable even when enabled in the BIOS. I have to re-start the system for Windows to see the esata connected drives.

I have read that perhaps Windows was not installed properly and the Marvell drivers are not working, but the device manager says the device is working.

My system is Win7 x64
Marvell controllers (Marvell 91xx Sata 6G controller) is listed in device manager as a Storage Controller and not under IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers (that's where the Intel controller is).

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the Intel ports for hot plugging and the Marvell ones for internal disks that you won't be hot swapping? The secondary SATA controllers on motherboards often have such issues I've found. (assuming you need 6gbps eSATA; otherwise just use any of the 6 onboard ones.